# Segregate data between 2 intervals based on an identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

One of my friends had this Q to me and I am too puzzled.

His team is loading a DW and the data keeps coming in incremental and full load fashion on an adhoc basic. Now there is identifier flag that says
as to when the full load has started or stopped. Now we need to collect and then segregate all full load.

For ex:

```
create table #tmp (
  id int identity(1,1) not null,
  name varchar(30) null,
  val int null
)

insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'detroit', 3
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'california', 9
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'houston', 1
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'los angeles', 4
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'newyork', 8
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'chicago', 1
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'seattle', 9
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'michigan', 6
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'atlanta', 9
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'philly', 6
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'brooklyn', 8

drop table #tmp
```

The rule is:

whenever val is 9, the full load starts; whenever val is 8, the full
 load stops; (or when whenever next val is 8, full load stops).

In this case, for full load, I should only collect these records:

> **id  name  val** 
>       
> 3  houston  1
>       
> 4  los angeles  4
>       
> 10  philly  6

My Approach so far:

```
;with mycte as (
    select id, name, val, row_number() over (order by id) as rnkst 
    from #tmp
    where val in (8,9))
SELECT *
FROM mycte y
WHERE val = 9
    AND Exists (
        SELECT * 
        FROM mycte x 
        WHERE x.id = 
                      ----> this gives start 9 record but not stop record of 8
                      (SELECT MIN(id)    
                      FROM mycte z 
                      WHERE z.id > y.id)
            AND val = 8)
```

I do not want to venture into cursor within cursor approach but with a CTE , please enlighten!

> **UPDATE:** 
>   
> As mentioned by one of the answerers I am restating the rules. 
>   
> --> the full load records start coming AFTER 9. (9th records are NOT included)
>   
> --> the full load continues till it sees immediate 8.
>   
> --> So effectively all records BETWEEN 9 and 8 form small chunks of full load
>   
> --> An individual 9th record itself does not get considered as it has no 8 as partner
>   
> --> The result set shown below satisfies these conditions

Comment: Shouldnt michigan also be collected? And how is Atlanta supposed to be dealt with since it is a double start?

Comment: You have 3 starts but 2 ends. How do you want that handled?

Comment: @justin...now the rule is that we should have an 8 accompanied by 9 to form a start-stop pair. Now since atlanta (9) record doesnt have its immediate accompanying partner i.e. 6 it should not be included. The more imp. thing here is to capture in-between records from all such pairs 9-8 rather than including or not including 9 records as these can be included with just a filter clause where val=9 easily, if needed.

Comment: @justin...michigan cannot be considered as 9-8 pair is not yet formed and is broken with another 9 record i.e. atlanta

Comment: @Ram you need to fix your logic.  That's a pretty convoluted and ridiculous use case.

Comment: @jnk..we are only looking for in-between records of 9 and 8 and none else...it is like switching ON button as soon as we see 9 and OFF immediately when 8 is seen and then collecting all these records into one table as full load. so we can effectively ignore other records outside of these lower and upper limits 9 and 8 records. for ex: detriot can be safely ignored.

Comment: @jnk...yes this DW load process is totally weird and me too hearing it for the first time but the SQL fun part of it intrigued me to venture into it...i would like to see if it really cant be done before giving up so early...

Comment: @ram. You need to update your question as the rules you are staying here do not match. Even here you contradict yourself by saying 9 is on until an 8, yet you say to ignore Michigan and atlanta? I would also say this is more convoluted than interesting, but that is just me

Comment: @justin....I am sorry if it wasnt clear...as i said in the comments above...9 alone is not enough....9 should be followed by 8 to consider in-between records...9th record is non-inclusive...the result set was there all the time since I initially posted but i will update q too now...

Comment: Thanks, I would suggest updating the line that explains the 9/8 logic to say something more like this: If a 9 is recorded, and another is recorded after it, but before the 8, then the new 9 takes precedence and the older 9 is ignored.....Or something like that, as it still reads to me that a 9 starts, and an 8 stops, everything in between is counted, even if it is a duplicate 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if my command of English will allow me to explain my approach fully, but I'll try, just in case it can help.

1. Rank all the rows and rank the bounds (`val IN (8, 9)`) separately.
2. Join the subset where `val = 8` with the subset where `val = 9` on the condition that the bound ranking of the former should be exactly 1 (one) greater than that of the latter.
3. Join the subset of non-`(8, 9)` rows to the result set of Step 2 on the condition that the (general) ranking should be between the ranking of the `val = 9` subset and that of the `val = 8` one.

Here's the query to illustrate my attempt at verbal description:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk       = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id),
    bound_rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY CASE WHEN val IN (8, 9) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
      ORDER BY id
    )
  FROM #tmp
)
SELECT
  load.id,
  load.name,
  load.val
FROM       ranked AS eight
INNER JOIN ranked AS nine ON eight.bound_rnk = nine.bound_rnk + 1
INNER JOIN ranked AS load ON load.rnk BETWEEN nine.rnk AND eight.rnk
WHERE eight.val = 8
  AND nine .val = 9
  AND load .val NOT IN (8, 9)
;
```

And you might not believe me but, when I tested it, it did return the following:

```
id name        val 
-- ----------- --- 
3  houston     1   
4  los angeles 4   
10 philly      6
```

Comment: @Andrily...very good explanation and the result is a correct match!...partition with case was new learning for me ....thanks for proving it can be done and easily too!

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a way to do this without a while loop or possibly a recursive cte that is going to be complex. So, my question would be if this is at all possible to accomplish in code? SQL is not as strong as a procedural language, so code would handle this better. If this is not an option, then I would go with a while loop (MUCH better than a cursor). I will create the SQL for this shortly.

```
/*
drop table #tmp
drop table #finalTmp
drop table #startStop
*/

  create table #tmp (
  id int identity(1,1) not null,
  name varchar(30) null,
  val int null
)

insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'detroit', 3
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'california', 9
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'houston', 1
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'los angeles', 4
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'newyork', 8
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'chicago', 1
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'seattle', 9
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'michigan', 6
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'atlanta', 9
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'philly', 6
insert into #tmp (name, val) select 'brooklyn', 8

CREATE TABLE #Finaltmp
    (
        id INT,
        name VARCHAR(30),
        val INT
    )

    SELECT id, val, 0 AS Checked
    INTO #StartStop
    FROM #tmp
    WHERE val IN (8,9)

    DECLARE @StartId INT, @StopId INT
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #StartStop WHERE Checked = 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @StopId = id
        FROM #StartStop
        WHERE EXISTS 
            --This makes sure we grab a stop that has a start before it
            (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #StartStop AS TestCheck
                WHERE TestCheck.id < #StartStop.id AND val = 9
            )
        AND Checked = 0 AND val = 8
        ORDER BY id

        --If no more starts, then the rest are stops
        IF @StopId IS NULL
            BREAK

        SELECT TOP 1 @StartId = id
        FROM #StartStop
        WHERE Checked = 0 AND val = 9 
            --Make sure we only pick up the 9 that matches
            AND Id < @StopId
        ORDER BY Id DESC

        IF @StartId IS NULL
            BREAK

        INSERT INTO #Finaltmp
        SELECT * 
        FROM #tmp
        WHERE id BETWEEN @StartId AND @StopId
            AND val NOT IN (8,9)

        --Make sure to "check" any values that fell in the middle (double 9's)
        --If not, then you would start picking up overlap data
        UPDATE #StartStop
        SET Checked = 1
        WHERE id <= @StopId
    END

    SELECT * FROM #Finaltmp
```

I noticed that the data looked a little wonky, so I tried to put some edge case checks and comments about them

Comment: Thanks Justin....yeah the loop within a loop will work no doubt as we can keep on appending records to a dummy table starting from 9 till we reach 8 and exit loop after all records but a truly recursive CTE might be real beast..

Comment: @justin....sorry it gives incorrect results as michigan record is picked up wrongly and so is brooklyn...

Comment: I just updated it after seeing your updated requirements above. I gave the entire code that makes this work (including the initial load). I just had to begin with stop and move back to start since you only want the pairs that match perfectly.  I do not believe a recursive CTE would work because of some of the constraints within it. As well as, CTE's are often a way of making code more readable. And, in this case, I think the CTE (if possible) would be more confusing than the temp table way